# Find key type of second array by matching key id of second array with key id of first array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Maybe the type of my question is not quite clear, but i don't know a better way to explain what i need. Here is the thing i am working on some custom page in WordPress and i have input fields in an array. The input fields in that array match the id's of second array, but i actually need to get the type field of second array that match the id of first array.

Here is example of first array

```
$first_array = array(
  'sample_text' => 'some text here',
  'sample_textarea' => 'some text here in textarea field',
  'sample_upload' => 'http://somelink.com/someimage.jpg'
);
```

And here is the second array.

```
$second_array = array(
   array(
     'type' => 'upload',
     'id' => 'sample_upload',
     'title' => 'Sample upload button'
   ),

   array(
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'id' => 'sample_text',
      'title' => 'Sample text field'
   ),

   array(
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'id' => 'sample_textarea',
      'title' => 'Sample textarea field'
   ),
);
```

So basically the second array is used in first place to generate an input fields in front-end, but upon form submit the form submits an array which looks like first example, so now on first array i need to loop for each input and match the id's of second and first array but when id's are match i need to take the type field and apply filter with that type field name.

So basically

```
// loop through inputs in the array
foreach( $first_array as $key => $value ) {

    // Now the first $key would be 'sample_text'

    // How to search $second_array for 'id' with 'sample_text'

    // And if that 'id' exists, take the 'type' field and apply filter named same as that 'type' field

}
```

But i don't know exactly how i would loop through second array and get 'type' based on 'id'

Comment: So, you want the first one to be the index of the second one?

Comment: If that would work, i don't know, i have read on php.net and it looks like this is not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add useful keys to the second array, like so:

```
$second_array = array(
   'sample_upload' => array(
     'type' => 'upload',
     'id' => 'sample_upload',
     'title' => 'Sample upload button'
   ),
   'sample_text' => array(
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'id' => 'sample_text',
      'title' => 'Sample text field'
   ),
   'sample_textarea' => array(
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'id' => 'sample_textarea',
      'title' => 'Sample textarea field'
   ),
);
```

When looping over the first array, you can use the known keys to access the second array.

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
    $sa = $second_array[$key];
}
```

<sup>That loop would usually have some more error-checking code in there, e.g. to make sure that the key exists, which has been left out for the sake of brevity.</sup>

Comment: That's actually very useful idea, but i wonder how it will affect the rest of the code where i use this array, by logic it shouldn't affect because this is basically just naming a key in the array. Ill test this out today and see if it can work. If it works its very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `array_filter()` won't work as original though, so you could use the following instead

```
function checkKey($item, $k, $key) {
    return $item['id'] === $key;
}

foreach( $first_array as $key => $value ) {
    // Now the first $key would be 'sample_text'
    // How to search $second_array for 'id' with 'sample_text'
    $sa = $second_array[array_walk($second_array, 'checkKey', $key)];
    // And if that 'id' exists, take the 'type' field and apply filter named same as that 'type' field
}
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work, or i can't figure it out.